# Can I find $b$ from $a = b \times c$?

Tags: vector-analysis, cross-product, frenet-frame

So I just started studying the TNB (or Frenet-Serret) frame, where **B = T × N**. Then my book also goes on to say that **T = N × B** and **N = B × T**. Basically, we can find a new valid cross-product equation by "shifting" the terms over the equality sign. My question is, is this property general for *all* cross products **a = b × c**, or just something unique to the TNB frame (or any other set of 3 vectors that meet particular criteria - if so, I'd like to know those criteria)?

**P.S.** New to this site, so might be disregarding a lot of expected niceties. Thanks in advance for your consideration and time!

Comment: For a fixed $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf c$, not both zero, $\mathbf a=\mathbf b\times\mathbf c$ is either the equation of a line or, when $\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf c\ne0$, has no solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is very special indeed. This is the situation when you have a (right-handed) orthonormal set of vectors, i.e., three unit vectors that are perpendicular to one another (taken in the "right-handed" order). [Can you prove that this is a necessary condition for it to work?]

With regard to the title of your question (which seems totally different), the answer is no. You can add any multiple of $\mathbf c$ to $\mathbf b$ without changing the cross product.

Comment: Yeah, 5 mins after writing my question, I realised that it's only possible if two of the vectors in question are perpendicular unit vectors (their cross product will also naturally be a unit vecor perpendicular to each of them). So I understand that this is a necessary condition, but is it also sufficient?

Comment: Sufficiency is the easier one. The cross product of two orthogonal unit vectors is a unit vector orthogonal to them both.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer: 
$$ v \times w = sp(v) \cdot w $$
with 
$$ sp(v) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -v_3 & v_2 \\
v_3 & 0 & -v_1 \\
-v_2 & v_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so we have:
$$
a = b \times c = -c \times b = -sp(c) \cdot b
$$
Now we would look for the inverse, but
$$
det(sp(c)) = 0 
$$
so no inverse exists